# Parsing a user uploaded CSV file from ASP.NET into MySQL DB. Security Issues

Tags: asp.net, mysql, security, csv, sql-injection

I am writing an ASP.NET web site where users will be able to upload a .CSV file from which i want to extract the data into a table on a MySQL Database.  I was wondering what would be the safest way to do this by protecting against SQL injection or other dangers towards my database.

I was also wondering what would be the best way to extract this?  For example would it be recommended to use an API to extract the data straight from the back of a button push or should I push the file to a temporary location where a service may pick it up periodically?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just because the data's coming from a CSV files doesn't mean you have to do anything special for SQL injection prevention. The exact same techniques apply universally for that.

Comment: What Marc said. Sanitize your userinput, don't invent your own solution, use prepared statements, use a database user with the least possible rights...

Comment: What do you mean by prepared statements?  What techniques would you apply?

Answer (score 0):

Use prepared statements to use your CSV data in the backend. Prepared statements securely escape data to prevent SQL injection.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare(v=vs.71).aspx

Never create a dynamic string that uses data by joining or concatenating strings. Only use the prepared statements.

This is universal and should be used regardless of the input source.

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment.  I never use dynamic strings and always use parameters anyway but why does preparing statements securely escape them?  It doesnt mention anything about preventing sql injection on that msdn article.  Also the way you are suggesting would mean looping through every row in a datatable and inserting them individually.  I was wondering if there was anyway around this where i can import everything out the CSV in one go?